# Free list implementation not working properly

Tags: c, malloc, free

So, I have been assigned a task to implement a free list. A list where items that are going to be free:d are added to and later the list is free:d in one go. I have written the following:

```
#include <assert.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct list_t   list_t;

struct list_t {
    list_t*     succ;
    list_t*     pred;
    void*       data;
};

list_t* free_list;

void free_list_memory(void)
{
    list_t *p , *q;
    p = free_list;
    while (p != NULL) {
        q = p->succ;
        free(p);
        p = q;
    }
}

void add_to_free_list(list_t* add) {
    if (free_list != NULL) {
            add->pred = free_list->pred;
        add->succ = free_list;
        free_list->pred->succ = add;
        free_list->pred = add;
    } else {
        free_list = add;
        add->succ = add;
        add->pred = add;
    }

}

static double sec(void)
{
    struct timeval  tv;

    gettimeofday(&tv, NULL);

    return tv.tv_sec + 1e-6 * tv.tv_usec;
}

int empty(list_t* list)
{
    return list == list->succ;
}

list_t *new_list(void* data)
{
    list_t*     list;

    list = malloc(sizeof(list_t));

    assert(list != NULL);

    list->succ = list->pred = list;
    list->data = data;

    return list;
}

void add(list_t* list, void* data)
{
    list_t*     link;
    list_t*     temp;

    link        = new_list(data);

    list->pred->succ= link;
    link->succ  = list;
    temp        = list->pred;
    list->pred  = link;
    link->pred  = temp;
}

void take_out(list_t* list)
{
    list->pred->succ = list->succ;
    list->succ->pred = list->pred;
    list->succ = list->pred = list;
}

void* take_out_first(list_t* list)
{
    list_t* succ;
    void*   data;

    if (list->succ->data == NULL)
        return NULL;

    data = list->succ->data;

    succ = list->succ;
    take_out(succ);
    free(succ);

    return data;
}

static size_t nextsize()
{
#if 1
    return rand() % 4096;
#else
    size_t      size;
    static int  i;
    static size_t   v[] = { 24, 520, 32, 32, 72, 8000, 16, 24, 212 };

    size = v[i];

    i = (i + 1) % (sizeof v/ sizeof v[0]);

    return size;
#endif
}

static void fail(char* s)
{
    fprintf(stderr, "check: %s\n", s);
    abort();
}

int main(int ac, char** av)
{
    int     n = 50;     /* mallocs in main. */
    int     n0;
    list_t*     head;
    double      begin;
    double      end;
    double      t = 2.5e-9;

    if (ac > 1)
        n = atoi(av[1]);

    n0 = n;

    head = new_list(NULL);

    printf("check starts\n");

    begin = sec();

    while (n > 0) {
        add(head, malloc(nextsize()));
        n -= 1;

        if ((n & 1) && !empty(head)) {
            add_to_free_list(take_out_first(head)); //before free(take_out_first(head))
        }
    }
    printf("Done");

    while (!empty(head)) 
        add_to_free_list(take_out_first(head)); //before free(take_out_first(head))


    free_list_memory(); //added line
    end = sec();

    printf("check is ready\n");
    printf("total = %1.3lf s\n", end-begin);
    printf("m+f   = %1.3g s\n", (end-begin)/(2*n0));
    printf("cy    = %1.3lf s\n", ((end-begin)/(2*n0))/t);
    return 0;
}
```

Running the code gives:

```
a.out(10009,0x7fff79ec0300) malloc: *** error for object 0x7fe160c04b20: pointer being freed was not allocated
*** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug
DoneAbort trap: 6
```

Running in valgrind gives:

```
check starts
==10011== Invalid read of size 8
==10011==    at 0x1000009B8: free_list_memory (check.c:20)
==10011==    by 0x100000D8B: main (check.c:163)
==10011==  Address 0x10081e270 is 0 bytes inside a block of size 423 free'd
==10011==    at 0x10000894F: free (in /usr/local/Cellar/valgrind/HEAD/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-darwin.so)
==10011==    by 0x1000009CA: free_list_memory (check.c:21)
==10011==    by 0x100000D8B: main (check.c:163)
==10011==
==10011== Invalid free() / delete / delete[] / realloc()
==10011==    at 0x10000894F: free (in /usr/local/Cellar/valgrind/HEAD/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-darwin.so)
==10011==    by 0x1000009CA: free_list_memory (check.c:21)
==10011==    by 0x100000D8B: main (check.c:163)
==10011==  Address 0x10081e270 is 0 bytes inside a block of size 423 free'd
==10011==    at 0x10000894F: free (in /usr/local/Cellar/valgrind/HEAD/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-darwin.so)
==10011==    by 0x1000009CA: free_list_memory (check.c:21)
==10011==    by 0x100000D8B: main (check.c:163)
==10011==
==10011==
==10011== More than 10000000 total errors detected.  I'm not reporting any more.
==10011== Final error counts will be inaccurate.  Go fix your program!
==10011== Rerun with --error-limit=no to disable this cutoff.  Note
==10011== that errors may occur in your program without prior warning from
==10011== Valgrind, because errors are no longer being displayed.
==10011==
^C==10011==
==10011== HEAP SUMMARY:
==10011==     in use at exit: 38,785 bytes in 423 blocks
==10011==   total heap usage: 602 allocs, 6,176,342 frees, 149,153 bytes allocated
==10011==
==10011== LEAK SUMMARY:
==10011==    definitely lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==10011==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==10011==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==10011==    still reachable: 4,120 bytes in 2 blocks
==10011==         suppressed: 34,665 bytes in 421 blocks
==10011== Rerun with --leak-check=full to see details of leaked memory
==10011==
==10011== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==10011== ERROR SUMMARY: 10000000 errors from 2 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

Now, I don't understand what's wrong since I am removing elements from the list that have been created using malloc...

Comment: IMO,  that is too much code to go through to diagnose the problem(s).

Comment: This is supposed to be a circular list, right ?? If so, give pause to what `free_list_memory` does once the last `succ` wraps around and is once again the value held in `free_list`. The madness has to end somewhere.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As [WhozCraig](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1322972/whozcraig) [diagnosed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30159582/free-list-implementation-not-working-properly#comment48427496_30159582), the problem is more that the code does not stop when it gets to the end of the free list because it is a circular list and the termination condition is looking for null pointers that don't exist.

You can fix most of the problems by rewriting `free_list_memory()` as:

```
static void free_list_memory(void)
{
    if (free_list == 0)
        return;
    list_t *p = free_list;
    do
    {
        list_t *q = p->succ;
        // free(p->data);  // Removed: see commentary below!
        free(p);
        p = q;
    } while (p != free_list);
}
```

With that change, I get one unfreed memory block of size 24 (on a 64-bit build).  So there is one `list_t` not being freed.  That item is in `head`; it happens to have a NULL data pointer, so you can fix that final leak with:

```
free(head);
```

at the end of `main()`.

### Surprise!

*At one time, I commented:*

> You also need to free the data as well as the list entry.

Somewhat to my surprise, on retesting, that isn't necessary.  In fact, on my machine, in `free_list_memory()`, all the data pointers are null.  That's actually unfortunate — `malloc()` is returning zeroed data.  What actually happens is that the list freeing code releases the original `list_t` pointer that held the data, and then adds the original data pointer to the free list, treating it as a `list_t` structure.  That gets iffy if the size of the allocated block (a random number from `nextsize()`) is smaller than a `list_t`.

To fix the problems and get a really clean run, even with different numbers of entries, I created this instrumented version of the code (with WhozCraig's function active).

#### Revised code

Note that the code ensures that the space allocated is at least as big as a `list_t` structure; that is crucial to avoid memory access errors (on longer runs; I used 200 to get problems with small allocations without adding `sizeof(list_t)` because it so happens that the first 50 allocations are always big enough).

```
#include <assert.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/time.h>

typedef struct list_t   list_t;

struct list_t {
    list_t*     succ;
    list_t*     pred;
    void*       data;
};

list_t* free_list;

static
void free_list_memory(void)
{
    if (!free_list)
        return;

    // terminate "last" node (the node that refers
    //  back to the node pointed to by free_list,
    //  including a potential self-referencing node)
    free_list->pred->succ = NULL;

    // now run the loop. uses free_list as the iterator
    // as it will finish with NULL, as it will be empty.
    while (free_list)
    {
        void *p = free_list;
        if (free_list->data == 0)
            printf("2 %p: data is null\n", free_list);
        //free(free_list->data);  // Not necessary
        free_list = free_list->succ;
        free(p);
    }
}

#if 0
static void free_list_memory(void)
{
    if (free_list == 0)
        return;
    list_t *p = free_list;
    do
    {
        list_t *q = p->succ;
        // free(p->data);  // Removed: see commentary below!
        free(p);
        p = q;
    } while (p != free_list);
}
#endif

#if 0
/* Broken code from question - does not handle circular list */
void free_list_memory(void)
{
    list_t *p , *q;
    p = free_list;
    while (p != NULL) {
        q = p->succ;
        free(p);
        p = q;
    }
}
#endif

static
void add_to_free_list(list_t* add) {
    if (free_list != NULL) {
        add->pred = free_list->pred;
        add->succ = free_list;
        free_list->pred->succ = add;
        free_list->pred = add;
    } else {
        free_list = add;
        add->succ = add;
        add->pred = add;
    }
    add->data = 0;  // Added to avoid access to uninitialized data warning from valgrind
}

static double sec(void)
{
    struct timeval  tv;

    gettimeofday(&tv, NULL);

    return tv.tv_sec + 1e-6 * tv.tv_usec;
}

static
int empty(list_t* list)
{
    return list == list->succ;
}

static
list_t *new_list(void* data)
{
    list_t*     list;

    list = malloc(sizeof(list_t));
    printf("1: data address is %p\n", data);

    assert(list != NULL);

    list->succ = list->pred = list;
    list->data = data;

    return list;
}

static
void add(list_t* list, void* data)
{
    list_t*     link;
    list_t*     temp;

    link        = new_list(data);

    list->pred->succ= link;
    link->succ  = list;
    temp        = list->pred;
    list->pred  = link;
    link->pred  = temp;
}

static
void take_out(list_t* list)
{
    list->pred->succ = list->succ;
    list->succ->pred = list->pred;
    list->succ = list->pred = list;
}

static
void* take_out_first(list_t* list)
{
    list_t* succ;
    void*   data;

    if (list->succ->data == NULL)
    {
        printf("3: %p - data is null\n", list->succ);
        return NULL;
    }

    data = list->succ->data;

    succ = list->succ;
    take_out(succ);
    free(succ);

    return data;
}

static size_t nextsize(void)
{
#if 1
    size_t v = rand() % 4096 + sizeof(list_t);
    printf("Size: %zu\n", v);
    return v;
    //return rand() % 4096;
#else
    size_t      size;
    static int  i;
    static size_t   v[] = { 24, 520, 32, 32, 72, 8000, 16, 24, 212 };

    size = v[i];

    i = (i + 1) % (sizeof v/ sizeof v[0]);

    return size;
#endif
}

#if 0
static void fail(char* s)
{
    fprintf(stderr, "check: %s\n", s);
    abort();
}
#endif

int main(int ac, char** av)
{
    int     n = 50;     /* mallocs in main. */
    int     n0;
    list_t*     head;
    double      begin;
    double      end;
    double      t = 2.5e-9;

    if (ac > 1)
        n = atoi(av[1]);

    n0 = n;

    head = new_list(NULL);

    printf("check starts\n");

    begin = sec();

    while (n > 0) {
        add(head, malloc(nextsize()));
        n -= 1;

        if ((n & 1) && !empty(head)) {
            add_to_free_list(take_out_first(head)); //before free(take_out_first(head))
        }
    }
    printf("Done\n");

    while (!empty(head)) 
        add_to_free_list(take_out_first(head)); //before free(take_out_first(head))

    free_list_memory(); //added line
    free(head);
    end = sec();

    printf("Check is ready\n");
    printf("total = %1.3lf s\n", end-begin);
    printf("m+f   = %1.3g s\n", (end-begin)/(2*n0));
    printf("cy    = %1.3lf s\n", ((end-begin)/(2*n0))/t);
    return 0;
}
```

The compilation options I habitually use (here I suppressed optimization to avoid having everything inlined in `main()`) require declarations of non-static functions, so I added `static` to each function except `main()` that was not already static.  I also added `(void)` in place of `()` when necessary.

```
$ gcc -g -std=c11 -Wall -Wextra -Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-prototypes \
>     -Wold-style-definition -Werror crashing.c -o crashing
$
```

#### Valgrind output

```
$ valgrind --leak-check=full --suppressions=suppressions crashing 10
==41722== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==41722== Copyright (C) 2002-2013, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==41722== Using Valgrind-3.11.0.SVN and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==41722== Command: crashing 10
==41722== 
--41722-- UNKNOWN mach_msg unhandled MACH_SEND_TRAILER option
--41722-- UNKNOWN mach_msg unhandled MACH_SEND_TRAILER option (repeated 2 times)
--41722-- UNKNOWN mach_msg unhandled MACH_SEND_TRAILER option (repeated 4 times)
1: data address is 0x0
check starts
Size: 447
1: data address is 0x10083f3e0
Size: 2825
1: data address is 0x100842440
Size: 3313
1: data address is 0x100842f90
Size: 3138
1: data address is 0x100843cd0
Size: 1946
1: data address is 0x10083f760
Size: 2784
1: data address is 0x100844960
Size: 3824
1: data address is 0x100845480
Size: 2582
1: data address is 0x100846410
Size: 3931
1: data address is 0x100846ed0
Size: 1125
1: data address is 0x100847ed0
Done
2 0x10083f3e0: data is null
2 0x100842440: data is null
2 0x100842f90: data is null
2 0x100843cd0: data is null
2 0x10083f760: data is null
2 0x100844960: data is null
2 0x100845480: data is null
2 0x100846410: data is null
2 0x100846ed0: data is null
2 0x100847ed0: data is null
Check is ready
total = 0.010 s
m+f   = 0.000487 s
cy    = 194959.641 s
==41722== 
==41722== HEAP SUMMARY:
==41722==     in use at exit: 39,132 bytes in 430 blocks
==41722==   total heap usage: 528 allocs, 98 frees, 71,359 bytes allocated
==41722== 
==41722== LEAK SUMMARY:
==41722==    definitely lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==41722==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==41722==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==41722==    still reachable: 26,034 bytes in 311 blocks
==41722==         suppressed: 13,098 bytes in 119 blocks
==41722== Reachable blocks (those to which a pointer was found) are not shown.
==41722== To see them, rerun with: --leak-check=full --show-leak-kinds=all
==41722== 
==41722== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==41722== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 15 from 15)
$
```

And you can see from the printed pointer values that the data added to the free list is indeed the data rather than the `list_t` structures holding the data.

It would be more conventional (and arguably sensible) to simply move the entire `list_t` structure from the active list to the free list, rather than freeing the `list_t` structure and using the data as the `list_t` structure on the free list.

Also, you should probably record the size of the data so you know whether the stuff on the free list can be used for a particular allocation.

Comment: Upticked. How interesting the completely different code than mine used to solve the same problem. Hat-tip.

Comment: If you're about to destroy the entire list, I guess it doesn't matter if you mutate it before you destroy it.  'Tis curious that on my Mac, I got the error about a block of size 423 too; it is a 'random' size, and it seems that the OP's platform has the same random number generator.  Which leads me to think that it must be on a Mac, too.  The `^C` in the output in the question is revealing too; that was necessary to stop the program, of course.

Comment: Fellow mac. Love mine (had awhile, MBA2011 and still good). Another hat-tip to getting Valgrind up and running on that platform. I've been so lazy I've not taken the effort to do it. Off-hand are you running 10.10.3 and is it fairly painless to get up and running? (sorry about the OT question in advance, btw).

Comment: I am using a 17" MBP (Early 2011) that's running Mac OS X 10.10.3 (and GCC 5.1.0, as well as XCode 6.3).  I built Valgrind from a copy of the Subversion repository (acquired on 2014-11-25, by the looks of it), so the version is reported as valgrind-3.11.0.SVN.  AFAICR, it was an uneventful compilation with that.

Comment: Thank you so very much. I'll put it (once again) on my todo list.

Comment: @WhozCraig: Two FYI's.  (1) I've expanded my answer because there was a surprise — but your code worked fine.  (2) If you decide you want my suppressions file (built on experience), send me email — see my profile. There's a surprising amount of leakage from the Mac runtime library (stuff called before `main()` ever gets called).

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the rest of your code is correct (and that is a *big* assumption), your free_memory_list function doesn't account for the fact *the list is circular*. The last node `succ` member refers back to the address held in `free_list`.

If that is the case, this is more akin to what you need:

```
void free_list_memory(void)
{
    if (!free_list)
        return;

    // terminate "last" node (the node that refers
    //  back to the node pointed to by free_list,
    //  including a potential self-referencing node)
    free_list->pred->succ = NULL;

    // now run the loop. uses free_list as the iterator
    // as it will finish with NULL, as it will be empty.
    while (free_list)
    {
        void *p = free_list;
        free_list = free_list->succ;
        free(p);
    }
}
```

I have to be honest. I did *not* diagnose the rest of this, but this is a glaring problem if this list is indeed circular.

Best of luck.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you using double linked (closed loop) list for your free list, if only go in one direction.

Your `void free_list_memory(void)` function crashes when trying to run a second time over your list.

Maybe this helps:

```
void add_to_free_list(list_t* add) {
    if (free_list != NULL) {
        free_list->succ = add;
        add->succ = NULL;
    } else {
        free_list = add;
        add->succ = NULL;
    }
}
```

Comment: As [WhozCraig](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1322972/whozcraig) [diagnosed](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30159582/free-list-implementation-not-working-properly#comment48427496_30159582), the problem is more that the code does not stop when it gets to the end of the free list because it is a circular list and the termination condition is looking for null pointers that don't exist.